# Swift Mapping, to and fro

Tags: swift, class, struct, mapping

I have a class

```
class shortcut: NSObject {
    @objc  var type: String
    @objc  var value: String
    @objc  var raw: UInt8
    init( ...)
    }
}
```

and a  struct

```
struct setting: Codable {
    var type: String
    var value: String
    var raw: Int
}
```

In order to store an array of shortcuts into a .plist I first map them to an array of settings as such:

```
let settings:[setting] = shortcuts.map({setting(type: $0.type, value: $0.value, raw: Int($0.raw))})
```

that is working fine. I then encode it, save it. On my way back, I read it, and decode it, but when I then try to map the [setting] back to [shortcut], as such:

```
let shortcuts:[shortcut] = settings.map({shortcut(type: $0.type, value: $0.value, raw: UInt8($0.raw))})
```

that line is flagged as erroneous, claiming

> Value of type '[setting]' has no member 'type'

and more of these

Where does my logic go wrong?

Comment: What type is `settings`? Is it an optional?

Comment: It seems like in the second line `settings` is a `[[setting]]`? Either there is a "fix" before to apply, or need a `flatMap()` before the `map()`. Unrelated, BUT, name your class/struct starting with an uppercase.

Comment: @sweeper: I declared setting as "var settings: [setting]?" Changed that into "var settings = [setting]()

Comment: @sweeper: still, the error message doesn't make sense to me

Comment: There is a [`map`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1539476-map) method on `Optional<Wrapped>`. You were calling that instead.

Answer (score 0):

In my case in Playground it works ...

```
import UIKit

var str = "Hello, playground"


class Shortcut: NSObject {
    @objc  var type: String
    @objc  var value: String
    @objc  var raw: UInt8
    
    init(type: String, value: String, raw: UInt8) {
        
        self.type = type
        self.value = value
        self.raw = raw
        
        super.init()
        
    }

}

struct Setting: Codable {
    var type: String
    var value: String
    var raw: Int
}

let  shortcuts: [Shortcut] = [
    Shortcut(type: "Type 1", value: "Value 1", raw: 1),
    Shortcut(type: "Type 2", value: "Value 2", raw: 2),
]

let settings:[Setting] = shortcuts.map({Setting(type: $0.type, value: $0.value, raw: Int($0.raw))})

dump(settings)


let roundBack:[Shortcut] = settings.map({Shortcut(type: $0.type, value: $0.value, raw: UInt8($0.raw))})


dump(roundBack)
```

Output:

```
▿ 2 elements
  ▿ __lldb_expr_1.Setting
    - type: "Type 1"
    - value: "Value 1"
    - raw: 1
  ▿ __lldb_expr_1.Setting
    - type: "Type 2"
    - value: "Value 2"
    - raw: 2
▿ 2 elements
  ▿ <__lldb_expr_1.Shortcut: 0x600001c43780> #0
    - super: NSObject
    - type: "Type 1"
    - value: "Value 1"
    - raw: 1
  ▿ <__lldb_expr_1.Shortcut: 0x600001c43600> #1
    - super: NSObject
    - type: "Type 2"
    - value: "Value 2"
    - raw: 2
```